# Setting a value to a field

Tags: php, javascript, get, field, auto-populate

So I have a field address in open.php, when a user starts to write something will fecth google addresses for auto-completion. When a user selects an address a marker is positioned on the map and lat/long fields are populated.

Now I added de possibility for the user fill the address field in a previous page, then open.php gets the address from url:

```
<input id="address" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['query']; ?>"/>
```

But then the JS script will not run to populate map, lat and long. How can I solve this?

(I need the possibility for the user fill the address field in a previous page, because user can enter directly on open.php)

Thank you!

Code from JS:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize(){
//MAP
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.599,6.134);
  var options = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    draggable: true
  });

}

$(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
      // geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term + ', lu' }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#latitude").val(ui.item.latitude);
        $("#longitude").val(ui.item.longitude);
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
  });

  //Add listener to marker for reverse geocoding
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': marker.getPosition()}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[0]) {
          $('#address').val(results[0].formatted_address);
          $('#latitude').val(marker.getPosition().lat());
          $('#longitude').val(marker.getPosition().lng());
        }
      }
    });
  });

});

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
$('#address').trigger('change');
```